# Problems on inference using GPU with OpenCV dnn and ONNX model

Tags: opencv, onnx, yolov5

I am trying to inference on a Jetson Xavier with OpenCV dnn. I have converted a YOLOv5m model to .onnx format . Afterwards I attempt to run inference with the model using the following codes with optimizations for GPU using CUDA AND cuDNN:

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX(yolov5m.onnx)
net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)
```

However in inference on Jetson Xavier with MAXN power mode, on a 1280 X 720 resolution video, my detections are very slow (approximately 109ms per frame). Using Jetson Power GUI I see that the usage of GPU is very low (on most frames less than 20% of GPU).

Also running the code without `(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)`and `setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)`, which means defaulting to use of CPU, shows that CPU usage is very high on every frame of video. GPU usage then becomes minimal.

I have also compiled OpenCV for running with CUDA and cuDNN, using this Git.
OpenCV build information is as follows:

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.6.0 =====================================
  Version control:               eb1afab-dirty

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            /home/jetsonjane/master/JEP/script/workspace/opencv_contrib-4.6.0/modules
    Version control (extra):     eb1afab-dirty

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2022-09-18T13:43:39Z
    Host:                        Linux 5.10.65-tegra aarch64
    CMake:                       3.16.3
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               RELEASE

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    NEON FP16

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 9.4.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined  
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          m pthread cudart_static dl rt nppc nppial nppicc nppidei nppif nppig nppim nppist nppisu nppitc npps cublas cudnn cufft -L/usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64 -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco barcode bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy gapi hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor mcc ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python2 python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking video videoio videostab wechat_qrcode xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 alphamat cvv java julia matlab ovis sfm ts viz
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI:                           GTK2
    GTK+:                        YES (ver 2.24.32)
      GThread :                  YES (ver 2.64.6)
      GtkGlExt:                  NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.1.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
    OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2_3)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.54.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.29.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.31.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.5.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   YES (1.16.3)
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)

  NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 11.4, CUFFT CUBLAS)
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             72 87
    NVIDIA PTX archs:

  cuDNN:                         YES (ver 8.3.2)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /home/jetsonjane/master/JEP/script/workspace/opencv-4.6.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.18)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.18)
    numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.16.5)
    install path:                lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2/python-2.7

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.8.10)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so (ver 3.8.10)
    numpy:                       /home/jetsonjane/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.19.4)
    install path:                lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/python-3.8

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /usr/local
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also during inference with the code I can see that 1 cuda device is recognized by the system:

```
count = cv2.cuda.getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()
print(count)
1
```

Are there any steps in configuration of CUDA,cuDNN,OpenCV that I am missing?
I would be thankful for any insights or solutions.

Comment: how did you measure the 109 ms per frame? Is it measured on the DNN part or is this total time per frame? If your cpu code (without dnn) is too slow, then gpu (dnn) will underperform (e.g. because in only 20% of the time a frame is present for the DNN). Can you show your inference code or create a dummy project that you can share where the same behaviour is visible?

Comment: @Micka can't share the code but I will work on creating a dummy version. The 109ms is the time it takes to load the model with dnn via `net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX(yolov5m.onnx)`

Comment: You should read the model only once, not for each frame! For each frame you should only do something like blob=cv.dnn.blobFromImage; net.setInput(blob); outputs = net.forward(outputlayers)

Comment: @Micka But once I fix this and read the model only once.  The process of conversion of images to blob and `outputs = net.forward(outputlayers)` happens for every frame. Correct? So by reading the model once, I will technically only save 100ms from the entire running time of the algorithm per frame.

Comment: not sure, you said that 109 ms is the time per frame and that 109 ms is the time for `net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX(yolov5m.onnx)`, which doesnt make much sense. So please write the sample code and we can talk about it in more detail. In C++ opencv you can even profile the time needed for pure inference by: 
     `double freq = getTickFrequency() / 1000;
     double t = net.getPerfProfile(layersTimes) / freq;
     string label = format("Inference time : %.2f ms", t);` See https://learnopencv.com/object-detection-using-yolov5-and-opencv-dnn-in-c-and-python/